# Jquery - Convert a link to button in dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an Email button in my html template, on clicking that button opens a dialog  which displays the email of the user. Below that Email I have a link  (in the Dialog). I need to convert that  into a jquery button before opening that dialog.

I can manually turn that  into a button with

`alertDialog.find('a').button();`

but I do not want to use this as a can since this is slow in rendering.

Please could you help

Comment: `.button()` is not a jQuery method. Are you using twitter js, if ya, you should tell it in question or say which plugin are you using. EDIT: sorry, looks like you anyway don't want to use it

Comment: Apply it a class which look like button.

Comment: i guess you could use replaceWith method

Answer (score 1):

Using `replaceWith` jQuery method:

```
alertDialog.find('a').each(function (_, e) {
    $(e).replaceWith($('<button/>', {
        text: e.innerHTML
    }).on('click', function () {
        window.location.href = e.href;
    }))
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UyWg8/)

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply. But this is not Working for me.

Comment: It works in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UyWg8/ so i guess you are making something wrong somewhere else or i don't understand what you are looking for

Comment: Yes thank you I was making mistake for `.on('click', function())`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
alertDialog.find('a').addClass("yourClass");

.yourClass{
display: inline-block;
padding: 6px 12px;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1.428571429;
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank You. But adding for adding a class,I need to include a new css. Which I am ignoring. This is a good solution too..

Comment: No need for new CSS, just a class in your existing CSS.